# Google Drive API - Pin and sync a file

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I tried following both the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/drive/android/pinning

And the demo:
https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/PinFileActivity.java

but I am still very confused on how to sync a pinned file between my local device and Google Drive.

According to the documentation:

> Pinning a file causes the latest version of that file's contents and metadata to be downloaded to the local device whenever a new version is available.

I implemented the code provided, but they only show to set a file as "pinned" without more explanation.

When and where do we specify where those pinned files must be downloaded on the local device?

I created test files that are well listed in the remote Google Drive, but I have no idea how those pinned files can be retrieved automatically on the local device as explained in the guide.

The demos provided are just too simple and limited...

Comment: After pinning, have you tried to update the file(e.g. remote Drive web access) to check if it will get the update on your device?

Comment: The pinned files are stored in Drive's internal memory. You can only access it via the API.

Answer (score 2):

I actually succeeded to accomplish what I wanted, I had to understand how it worked through several tests.

In my app I actually use the specific app folder to interact with Google Drive:

```
Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
```

This folder on Google Drive is accessed by the app only.

At first I thought I had to specify a folder on my device to indicate where the files from the Google Drive app folder should be downloaded but it does not work that way.

You just have to access this app folder directly and check if there were any changes inside it since the last time it was accessed.

So basically when the files were changed I copy them where I need in my app file structure.

Comment: Hi, I am kinda doing the same thing you were in this question, but I really can't get my head around it. How do I pin the files to google drive? and what kind should the file be? I would be thankful if you'd have a look at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890840/android-create-a-file-containing-an-arraylist-and-save-it-to-google-drive-app

Comment: @Yoann I'm stuck with pinning ans syncing and the documentation as you mention is poor. Would it be possible for you to provide an example how you accomplish this? I have a few questions. If you don't have an example I would like to ask them. I would really appreciate your help!!

Comment: @Marius I don't really have time right now but maybe contact me again on monday or tuesday and I'll check. You can contact me here: yhercouet@gmail.com